# Hyper-V private connection

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have the following setup on a host server running Windows Server 2012 R2:

- 1 virtual machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 with one private virtual network adapter
- 1 virtual machine running CentOS with one external network adapter and one private network adapter.

Is it possible to route the connection from the Windows Server VM to the Linux VM and get access to the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up the CentOS box to be a NAT router.

Set your networking up so that Windows and centos can ping each other on the private network, and the centos box can ping the internet (I've found you may need to give it a fixed address on the external vSwitch)

Then, on the Centos box, enable IP forwarding: in /etc/sysctl.conf add the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
then run `sysctl. -r /etc/sysctl.conf` to apply this.

To enable NAT, run `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` (assuming eth1 is the external adapter).
You can save the iptables settings on reboot by editing /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config. (You may need to install the package iptables-services).

With this, you should be able to ping out from your windows VM. For DNS on the windows VM, point it to the one your Hyper-V server sees.

Comment: I'll try it again, did almost everything you described, I could ping CentOS vm from windows but not the internet. When you say to put a fixed ip on the external vSwitch, you saying the HOST adapter? cause I my setup was using a fixed ip on both windows and linux adapters.

Comment: If everything is static addresses, that should be fine. I'm sure I've had troubles with VMs picking up DHCP addresses occasionally, I can't remember the circumstances.. Sorry, fixed addresses on all adapters on your 2 hosts yes, not the vswitch. So the windows VM's gateway is the address it can ping on centOS, you have routing enabled ok ('more /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward' returns a '1') and 'iptables -L -t nat' shows your masquerading entry in POSTROUTING with -o set to your external adapter?

Comment: The same thing should work without NAT assuming the routing is configured properly.

Comment: It worked guys. Thx guess I was doing some miss config. Did everything again and it was fine